# PHP - Preg replace pattern to replace / or & with space or without space if necessary

Tags: php, preg-match, preg-match-all

What is the `preg_replace` pattern to replace the `/` or `&` with `and` with and without space? The pattern should be able to replace all the below examples:

`This is J/J.` to `This is J and J.`.

`J/J, Y& S, and U / A are names.` to `J and J, Y and S and U and A are names.`.

`What does J /J or J & E mean?` to `What does J and J or J and E mean?`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<?php
   $text = "J/J, Y& S, and U / A are names.";
   $result = preg_replace('~[/&]~', ' and ', $text, -1);
   echo $result;
```